# Affecting another outside element using CSS

Tags: css, dom-events, styles, jquery-events, long-polling

I would like to attach a focus event listener to the first element and when it fires, then second element border will be red.

The first element is inside of the second element.

**The problem**: I cannot attach the event listener to the first element, because it does not exist when javascript / jQuery executes.

**Why?**: the first element loads long after the page loads because I use long poll on my website.

Because of this, I tried to use jQuery `.ready` method, but it did not work, because `.ready` fires too early. The first element loads long after `.ready` fires (the javascript / jQuery executes still too fast).

After this I tried to use CSS (CSS does not cares if elements exists or not, it works when the element loads after CSS loads), but I found only this:
[How to affect other elements when one element is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)

In the previous page the solution can be made with CSS only when second element is inside the first element or they are siblings. In my case the second element is outside of the first element, so I cannot use CSS. What do you think?

Comment: It may be possible to get the same effect using CSS but it depends on the relationship between the two elements - are they both positioned and is the outer one the first ancestor of the inner one that has position set?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea.

You can access the parent element in JS with `.parentNode`

You should add this JS to your website, and when you create the "first" element, give it these: `onfocus="parentStyle(this)"` and `onblur="parentStyleBack(this)"`.

```js
let bf;

function parentStyle(el) {
  parent = el.parentNode;
  bf = parent.style.border;
  parent.style.border = "2px solid #FF0000";
}

function parentStyleBack(el) {
  parent = el.parentNode;
  parent.style.border = bf;
}
```

```css
#outside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#inside {
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outside">
  <input id="inside" onfocus="parentStyle(this)" onblur="parentStyleBack(this)" placeholder="Click here to focus">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your structure allows then it can appear to be done with just CSS.

The requirement is that the outer element can be given a position but that the inner element and any intervening elements are not positioned.

That way a pseudo before element on inner can take on the dimensions of outer and thus provide the border.

```css
.outer {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background-color: lime;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.inner {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
  background-color: cyan;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner:hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 5px red;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Hover over me</div>
</div>
```